# Determine the number of samples needed with Bayes theorem

Tags: bayes-theorem, sampling

I have a simple sample statistic problem, but I am not sure that I solve it properly.

I have to enter many student marks to a test in an Excel table. After entering all $N$ marks, I want to know the sample size $S$ I should verify to have 95% chance at least that all my marks are correctly entered in the table.

I tried solving this with the Bayes theorem (which I often struggle to apply btw), here is my attempt :

- event $E$ : $S$ marks verified have been correctly entered in the table
- hypothesis $H$ : all the marks are correctly entered
- wanted : $\mathcal{P}(H|E) = 95\% $
- theorem : $\mathcal{P}(H|E) = \dfrac{\mathcal{P}(E|H)\mathcal{P}(H)}{\mathcal{P}(E)}$

I would then say that $\mathcal{P}(E|H) = 1$, $\mathcal{P}(H) = 75\%$ (let's say I a messy today and I may miss 1 mark out of 4), $\mathcal{P}(E) = \frac{S}{N}$ (not sure about this one), so that :

$$S = \frac{75}{95}N$$

So that for $100$ marks I should check $79$ marks. What leads me into thinking that I am very wrong here is that if I only wanted to be less sure that I correctly entered the marks (let's say $90\%$), I would have to check a larger sample $S$... Could you help me here ?

Disclaimer : I am not a statistician, so I apologize if I misused some concepts, I am just curious and I want to understand :)

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, but you are not writing the probabilities for the events of interest correctly.

Let $p$ be the probability of you making an error while entering one student's marks. Assuming that making an error in one student's marks is independent of making an error in other student's marks,

$$
\mathcal{P}(H) = (1 - p)^N \\
\mathcal{P}(E) = (1 - p)^S \\
\mathcal{P}(H|E) = (1 - p)^{N - S}
$$
For this to be more than 0.95, $S \geq N - \frac{\log{0.95}}{\log{(1-p)}}$. If you are unsure about the above expressions, read about the [Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) and [Binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) distributions.

Comment: No, from the question, some value for $p$ is assumed (0.25). We have to determine the sample size $S$.

Comment: Thank you for the maths! The results however still seems strange to me. Let's say $p=0.05$ (so I may report incorrectly 5% of the marks), for $N=100$ marks to report in my table. This gives me $S=99$. So I would have to check $99$ marks out of $100$ to be sure at $95\%$ that I reported them correctly? That is rather surprising, considering a mark can only be reported correctly or incorrectly, not partly one or the other... Or am I missing something?

Comment: In that case, where one mark is unchecked, because $p=0.05$, this unchecked mark has a 95% chance of being correct which is exactly what is required. In any specific instance, it will be correct or incorrect, but if you repeat this experiment many number of times, you will find that about 95% of the time you are correct.

Comment: I am sorry there must be something I just don't understand here. I may have badly explained my problem, but I do not want to check how much chance a given mark has to be correct, but a chance that at least 95% of marks are correct. So what troubles me here is that if I check for 99 marks out of 100 and they are correct, my chance of having at least 95% marks correct should be 100%. In fact I know for sure that at least 95% of marks are correct starting with 95 marks checked as correct... No ?